# Is there a difference between a file hash, and the hashed password for that file?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I'm having a hard time getting a straight answer on whether, say, an MD5 hash of a file is different from the hashed password to access said file.

For example, if one was trying a brute force attack against a hash taken from the file, would the result (if any) be usable as the password, or are these fundamentally different things?

Comment: in what context? generally speaking the two are completely different since if they were the same the password would have been identical to the file.

Comment: @gidim Perhaps you could elaborate in an answer? Your comment presumes a sufficient understanding of hashing that your distinction would be obvious. This is not the case. Would be happy to see some additional details thrown in to clarify this with some examples or more information.

Comment: in what context? where do you enter that password?

Comment: @gidim I don't understand what you're asking. How does the context relate to explaining the difference between these hashes?

Comment: Let me help out a little. For simplicity let's forget for now that collisions can easily be generated on MD5 hashes under the right conditions.  As a general rule, if 2 binary streams have the same hash, the streams (preimages) from which the hash was calculated were also the same.  So if the hash of a password to open a file is the same as the hash of that file, then the entire file *is* the password.  That will pretty much never happen, so you should expect the hash of a file and the hash of its password to differ pretty much every time.

Comment: You COULD set it up that way, but it would almost certainly lower the cryptographic strength. No one does this in practice, so I very much doubt anyone has done a cryptographic attack on a file assuming that they know the hash of the plaintext of the file. `md5sum my_file_to_encrypt.txt` copy the printed hash, then `openssl des3 -salt -in unencrypted-data.file` and paste the printed hash sum twice to set it as the password. The encryptor of a file sets the password or encryption key, so why would they pick the hash of the file as the password when a random/arbitrary string is much stronger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password will probably be a shortish string, like "paSs!w0rd".  Your file will be, say, a 1Mb document.  These two are very different things.  Because they are different their hashes are overwhelmingly likely to be different.  Hash functions are deliberately designed so that different inputs will result in very different hashes.  To show this, try comparing the MD5 hashes of "paSs!w0rd" and "paSs!w0rD" (with a capital D at the end).